# Aggregate array de duas ou mais coleções no mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, join, mongoose

Olá,

Eu tenho duas collections e quero fazer uma query das duas collections, como o "join" do sql. A relação entre as collections é feita da seguinte forma:

```
medico: [{
    medicoId: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'medicos'
    }
  }],
```

E cada documento vai ter a seguinte estrutura em json:

```
[
    {
        "nome": "clinica teste",
        "medico": [
            {
                "_id": "5e011a3796a5f80e3c0c8d20",
                "medicoId": {
                    "_id": "5dc5eef455a8f61698a0f2cd",
                    "nome": "Hancho Crutis",
                }
            },
            {
                "_id": "5e011a3796a5f80e3c0c8d1f",
                "medicoId": {
                    "_id": "5df16e5746783116709f09b7",
                    "nome": "camilinha",
                }
            }
        ],
    }
]
```

Para fazer o "join" no MongoDB eu vi que tenho que usar Aggregate. Eu já pesquisei e tentei bastante, mas sem sucesso. O código atual que eu tenho é esse, mas sempre me retorna nada.

```
Clinicas.aggregate([


    { $lookup: {
        from: "medicos",
        localField: "medico.medicoId.nome",
        foreignField: "nome",
        as: 'clinica_nome'
    }}, 
    { $unwind: "$medico"},
    { $match: {'medico.medicoId.nome': "camilinha" }},
```

**Model da Collection CLINICAS**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const UserSchema = new Schema({
  nome: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    maxlength: 50
  },
  medico: [{
    medicoId: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'medicos'
    }
  }],
  exame_consulta: [{
    exame_consulta_id: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'exames_consultas'
    }
  }],
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('clinicas', UserSchema);
```

**MODEL COLLECTION MÉDICOS**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const MedicoSchema = new Schema({
  nome:{
    type: String,
    required: true,
    maxlength: 80  
  },
  especialidade:{
    type: String,
    maxlength: 50
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('medicos', MedicoSchema);
```

Comment: Poste como está definida a estrutura das collections `medicos` e `clinicas`.

Comment: @user140828 adicionei. Apenas removi os outros campos para reduzir o código.

Answer (score 0):

Ola, Eu recomendo que você faça o `unwind` "medico" array primeiro e depois junte-se à outra coleção:

```
Clinicas.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$medico",
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      localField: "medico.medicoId.nome",
      foreignField: "nome",
      as: "medico",
    },
  },
  {
    $unwind: "medico",
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "medico.nome": "camilinha"
    }
  },
])
```